# Simple IPC via linux messages

Tags: c++, linux, message-queue

I'm trying to write some example of client-server application which uses linux messages. Here is my code:

```
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define MSG_SIZE 4096
#define MSG_MAX_COUNT 1024
#define MSG_TYPE_TO_UPPER 0
#define MSG_TYPE_EXIT 1
#define MQ_NAME "msg_queue"

namespace {
    int str_toupper(char *str)
    {
        int len = 0;
        for(; str[len]; ++len) {
            str[len] = toupper(str[len]);
        }
        return len;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: msg_queue (client|server)\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct mq_attr attr;    // MQueue attributes
    mqd_t mqd;      // MQueue descriptor
    char buf[MSG_SIZE]; // Msg buffer
    unsigned int type;  // Msg type(priority)

    // Set up MQueue attributes
    attr.mq_maxmsg = MSG_MAX_COUNT;
    attr.mq_msgsize = MSG_SIZE;
    attr.mq_flags = 0;
    attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;

    mqd = mq_open(MQ_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0664, &attr);
    if(mqd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "mq_open() failed for \""MQ_NAME"\": %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(strcmp(argv[1], "server") == 0) {
        while(mq_receive (mqd, buf, MSG_SIZE, &type) != -1) {
            if(type == MSG_TYPE_EXIT) {
                mq_unlink(MQ_NAME);
                mq_close(mqd);
                break;
            } else if(type == MSG_TYPE_TO_UPPER) {
                int len = str_toupper(buf);
                if(mq_send (mqd, buf, len, MSG_TYPE_TO_UPPER) == -1) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Server: mq_send() failed: %s", strerror(errno));
                }
            }
        }
    } else if(strcmp(argv[1], "client") == 0) {
        while(1) {
            printf("Input a message: <type>(0 - TO_UPPER, 1 - EXIT) <message>\n");
            scanf("%u %s", &type, buf);

            if(mq_send (mqd, buf, strlen(buf), type) == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Client: mq_send() failed: %s", strerror(errno));
            }

            if(type == MSG_TYPE_TO_UPPER) {
                if(mq_receive (mqd, buf, MSG_SIZE, &type) == -1) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Client: mq_receive() failed: %s", strerror(errno));
                }
                printf("\"%s\" received\n", buf);
            } else if(type == MSG_TYPE_EXIT) {
                mq_unlink(MQ_NAME);
                mq_close(mqd);
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: msg_queue (client|server)\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What is my mistake? It always prints error from the line 47 - `fprintf(stderr, "mq_open() failed for \""MQ_NAME"\": %s\n", strerror(errno));` with `errno = EINVAL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues:

- Your message queue name **must** begin with a `/` on Linux. See [`mq_overview(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html):

> Each message queue is identified by a name of the form
>     /somename; that is, a null-terminated string of up to NAME_MAX (i.e., 255)
>     characters consisting of an initial slash, followed by one or more characters,
>     none of which are slashes.

- `MSG_MAX_COUNT` is most likely above your system limits. It must be less than (or equal to) the `/proc/sys/fs/mqueue/max_size`. See [`mq_open(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/mq_open.3.html):

> `EINVAL`: O_CREAT was specified in oflag, and attr was not NULL, but
>                 `attr->mq_maxmsg` or `attr->mq_msqsize` was invalid.  Both of these fields
>                 must be greater than zero.  In a process that is unprivileged (does not
>                 have the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability), **`attr->mq_maxmsg` must be less
>                 than or equal to the msg_max limit**, and `attr->mq_msgsize` must be less
>                 than or equal to the msgsize_max limit.  In addition, even in a
>                 privileged process, `attr->mq_maxmsg` cannot exceed the HARD_MAX limit.
>                 (See mq_overview(7) for details of these limits.)

The other limit is probably ok, but you should verify it too.

Comment: Thank you @Mat. Your answer helped me to solve the problem. There was no this info in the site (http://www.users.pjwstk.edu.pl/~jms/qnx/help/watcom/clibref/mq_overview.html#MqStructures) I used to learn linux-messages

Comment: Yeah, you should always check the operating system's docs for these types of calls, the restrictions vary from one platform to the other. What you link to seems to be for QNX which is a bit special.